# PostgreSQL: Duration before another row is created with the same foreign key

Tags: postgresql, time, duration

Have table:

```
id, car_id, status, created_at
```

With data:

```
1, 180, active,   2017-04-02 10:12:00 +0600
2, 190, active,   2017-04-05 17:34:00 +0600
3, 180, inactive, 2017-05-10 16:59:00 +0600
4, 180, active,   2017-06-15 09:23:00 +0600
5, 180, inactive, 2017-07-10 19:12:00 +0600
```

I want to know how long car `180` was `active` the first time, then how long it was `inactive`, then how long it was `active` the second time.

I'm not very adept at SQL, but this is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
  start_log.car_id,
  start_log.status,
  MAX(start_log.updated_at) AS start_time,
  end_log.updated_at AS end_time,
  (end_log.updated_at - start_log.updated_at) AS duration
FROM
  car_availabilities AS start_log
INNER JOIN
  car_availabilities AS end_log ON (
    start_log.car_id = end_log.car_id
    AND
    end_log.updated_at > start_log.updated_at
  )
GROUP BY 
  start_log.status, 
  end_log.updated_at, 
  start_log.updated_at, 
  start_log.car_id
ORDER BY start_time
```

However, this produces the duration of time between each row, not just the next one in chronological order.

Can someone let me know how to get the expected result? i.e.

```
180, active, 2017-04-02 10:12:00 +0600, 2017-05-10 16:59:00 +0600, 38 days....
180, inactive, 2017-05-10 16:59:00 +0600, 2017-06-15 09:23:00 +0600, 35 days...
etc
```

thank you❣️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, lag(created_at, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY created_at) as prev_state_created_at
    FROM car_availabilities
)
SELECT *, (created_at - prev_state_created_at) as duration
FROM t
```

This is accomplished by using PostgreSQL window functions.

> `lag` returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows before the current row within the partition;

```
lag(created_at, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY created_at)
```

Comment: This should work, but you don't need the sub-select though: you can use directly `created_at - lag(created_at) over (...) as duration`. -- Although OP might need to handle the case, where there are two "following" rows are in the same `status` (i.e. `active` and then `active` again). But this depends on OP.

Comment: thank you, so much, @AlexM!! I never would have reached that answer without your help. Your blood is worth bottling.You too, @pozs! Very valuable insights.